# Form works in Admin correctly but not in Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-smart-selects

I'm trying to use `Django-smart-selects` which should allow you to create chained `forms`.

So I've decided to try it on a simple example before adding to my project. The problem is that it works correctly in `Admin` but it does not work in template (rendered using view method).

It does not raises any error, but it does not populate `Country` drop down menu when I choose `Continent` in continent drop down menu.

Please, note that the problem isn't probably in MODELS.PY since it works correctly in Admin.

There are 3 Locations:

1. America - NewYork
2. America - Texas
3. Africa - Morocco

There are two forms - Continent and Country. If I haven't choose `Continent`, I'm not able to choose any Country. If I choose America, the second menu is populated with NewYork and Texas, which is correct. This is in Admin. In template, I can choose Continent

Here is the code:

FORMS.PY:

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('newcontinent','newcountry',)
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def test(request):
    location_form = LocationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        print request.cleaned_data
    return render(request,'test.html', context={'location_form':location_form})
```

ADMIN.PY:

```
...
admin.site.register(Continent)
admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(Location)
...
```

URLS.PY:

```
...
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
...
```

TEST.HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ location_form }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

MODELS.PY:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Location(models.Model):
    newcontinent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    newcountry = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, # the model where you're populating your countries from
        chained_field="newcontinent", # the field on your own model that this field links to
        chained_model_field="continent", # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
        show_all=True, # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load the form media in your test.html as {{ form.media }} or for your case {{ location_form.media }} so as to include the javascript/css files.